# CakePHP Combining Tables into a Form

Tags: php, cakephp, model, controller

I've just began using CakePHP and I have a question. I'm creating sort of a Task Manager system.

I have a 'Tasks' table, and this table has a `user_id` field for assigning a task to a user.

When I baked the application, the generated form has a `user_id` which was automatically linked to the `users` table, but I want to show the user's `username` instead of the `user_id` - how would I go about doing this?

Also, I need for when the form is saved, it saves the `user_id` into the field and not the `username` - So it needs to display the `username` for ease of use but save the `user_id`.

I'm still new to this whole Model and Controller so I'm not sure how I'd manage to do this. Thanks.

**Update:**

Here's where I am so far. In my jobs `add.ctp` I have added this code to help generate the form field:

```
foreach ($users as $user):
    $options_array[$user['id']] = $user['username'];
endforeach;
print_r($options_array);
echo $this->Form->input('user_id', $options_array);
```

Unfortunately the `print_r` gives me:

```
Array ( [2] => 2 )
```

And not the desired output:

```
Array ( [2] => Dan )
```

`$users` is defined in the `job_controller.php` as so:

```
$users = $this->Job->User->find('list');
$clients = $this->Job->Client->find('list');
$stages = $this->Job->Stage->find('list');
$this->set(compact('users', 'clients', 'stages'));
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
Dan

Comment: What is the command you used to get the $users array.  I think your missing something.  if you did a query against the User model using ->find to get the $users array, it should return an array like array([0] => array( 'User' => array ('id' => 1, 'username' => 'whatever the username is', ... etc the rest of the fields in the `users` table), 'AssociatedTable' => array(... blah blah))

Comment: @stephenbayer I've updated where I got the $users variable. Just wondering why $options_array ignored the username. Basically, in order to format the select options the way I need they need to be in the format: `Array ( [value] => text, [value] = text )` etc.

Comment: the ->find('list') should already do that for you.  You don't need the $option_array.  Did you have the $displayField in your User Model set to 'username'?  if so the find by list should _already_ return the array the way you want it. If not, you need to add 'username' to the fields in the find call, like in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only looking for the id and username, then using the list should be cool, but you have to specify the username field.

```
$users = $this->Job->User->find('list', array('fields' => array('User.username'));
```

That should return the array as such:

```
array (
  [1] => 'username_for_id_1',
  [2] => 'username_for_id_2',
  ...  all the other records...
  [114] => 'username for id_114'
)
```

If you need more information from the User table, then you should use the ->find('all').

```
$users->Job->User->find('all');
// $users is now:
// array (
//    [0] => array (
//        'User' => array(
//            'id' => 1,
//            'username' => 'username',
//             ... the rest of the fields
//         )
//        Other affiliated models will be included with the 'User' if 
//        you haven't set 'recursive' = -1
//    )
// )
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data is the best reference to various methods of using the find on the Models.

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to accept. Only just managed to have a go and it works! Awesome, cheers!